# Sharing folders in shared drives using Google Drive API Client

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Using the google drive UI, it seems like you can now share folders in a shared drive within your organization (shown in picture below). I created a python script to attempt to share that same folder with a member of the organization and received the following error:

> HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/... returned "Sharing folders that are inside a shared drive is not supported."

I know that sharing folders in a shared drive was not possible before, but it seems like now it is using the UI. So my question is why can I share a folder through the UI but not through the Google Drive API Python Client?

[image: Screenshot of folder sharing]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you are experiencing? When trying to share a folder inside a shared Drive through the UI, the `share` button [is disabled](https://i.imgur.com/jMkPrx5.png). Have you tried to actually share the folder?

Comment: Yes, I was able to share a folder with someone. I should also mention that I have a G Suite Business account.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7662202), only specific files can be shared outside the shared drive, but not folders. I'd suggest you to contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), I think what you're experiencing in the UI might not be intended behaviour.